# How to run more than just one query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I need to run the different SQL queries in Laravel:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE; DROP TABLE; UPDATE something etc
```

By surfing the web, I came to realize that I need to use DB::unprepared($sql) method. The problem is that this method just returns TRUE or FALSE. 
As I have to run lots a queries, I need to minimize the no of queries by grouping them in order not put load on MySQL.
Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Your query provided will only return results from `answers`, so running this query would result in nothing other than just running the second query separately?

Comment: Have you heard of eloquent? I assume ur super new to laravel. You might want to just follow laravels introduction guide

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You'd probably benefit from setting up some relationships between questions and answers, then you can just do some Eloquent eager loading with `$question = Question::with('answer')->where('id', $id)->get();` and then access the answer with `$question->answer->answer_text_field`

Comment: @BertMaurau rather, it will return results from `questions`

Comment: @BehzadMoradi so how are we meant to accurately help if the query in the question isn't an accurate representation of what you're doing?

Comment: This guy is editing the question every time, needs moderator attention, at first it was for users, then it was for questions, answers table, then it's for this table, please report.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to run the following query

**Nope, you don't.**

That's not a single query but two queries. Therefore you have to run these two queries separately. This is how web applications work.

Using Eloquent models it would be like

```
$question = Question::whereIn('id', [ 1 ])->get();
$answer = Answer::whereIn('id', [ 12 ])->get();
```

> I need to minimize the no of queries by grouping them in order not put load on MySQL.

Nope, you don't. Grouping queries like this **does not reduce the number of queries** and **does not affect the load on MySQL**.

> Is there a way to tackle this problem?

There is no problem for starter. Just run your queries one by one, like everyone does.

Comment: Well, Eloquent is bundled with Laravel so apparently you *can* use it. But using Eloquent models is not a requirement. You can use consequent calls to `DB::select` for all your queries. SQL queries are **never** executed "at the same time" no matter how you would call them. So just call them one by one and you're set.